# Pandas column value based on previous rows' values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a time series dataframe, that is ordered and grouped by a user id

```
2023-07-15 14:38:21,1,2023-07-15 14:38:21,2023-07-15 15:20:45,False, 1
2023-07-15 15:20:45,2,2023-07-15 14:38:21,2023-07-15 15:34:18,False, 1
2023-07-15 15:34:18,3,2023-07-15 15:20:45,2023-12-23 16:20:55,True, 1
2023-12-23 16:20:55,4,2023-07-15 15:34:18,2023-12-23 16:20:55,False, 1
```

What I would like to do is to create a column, signifying the lifetime, that is it would start at 1, but whenever the condition is true, the value would go up. For example

```
condition  new_col
false, 1
false, 1
false, 1 
true, 1
false, 2
true, 2
true, 3
false, 4
```

I know this can be done quite easily with a for-loop, but is there a faster way using pandas methods?

For loops are an option, but due to the size of the data, the run time is painfully slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), for starting by `1` use `fill_value=1`, thank you @Panda Kim:

```
df['new_col'] = df['condition'].shift(fill_value=1).cumsum()
print (df)
   condition  new_col
0      False        1
1      False        1
2      False        1
3       True        1
4      False        2
5       True        2
6       True        3
7      False        4
```

If need solution per groups by `id` use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function:

```
df['new_col'] = (df.groupby('id')['condition']
                     .transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=1).cumsum()))
print (df)
   id  condition new_col
0   a      False       1
1   a      False       1
2   a      False       1
3   a       True       1
4   a      False       2
5   a       True       2
6   a       True       3
7   a      False       4
8   b       True       1
9   b      False       2
10  b      False       2
11  b       True       2
```

Comment: how about `fill_value=1`?

Comment: I got the solutions per group by using two groupbys instead, one for `shift()` and one for `cumsum`. Don't know how it compares to using `transform()` with a lambda function in terms of performance.

Comment: @bachts - what is number of groups? What is size of groups? What is size of DataFrame?